# Custom UiCollectionViewCell class init not being called

Tags: ios, swift2, ios9, xcode7, uicollectionviewcell

Hi I'm using this code to try and make the text resize though I can't seen to get the label to resize. Also the init method in the custom class is not being called. Here is my code:

```
class Cell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!


    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        print("init—>Not being called???\n")
        self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        self.cell.label.sizeToFit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }


}
```

What can I do to get the init to call so.  I have also tried adjusting the text in the method

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath
```

Though the text size of the label is not changing,
Here's what the cell looks like with a longs string.
[image]
Thanks in advance for your help.

If I place -

> adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth

or

> sizeToFit

:

into ->

```
 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true  // causes error
        self.label.sizeToFit()
    }
```

[image]
I also get an error.

Comment: do you already try to override awakeFromNib() ?

Comment: I just tried  awakeFromNib() and it is being called though the text is not adjusting still. Maybe when I'm assigning the text in the cellforItemAtIndex is overriding something.

Comment: @GerardGrundy `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` should definitely be getting called. Place a break point there or some logs (I see you haven't). This is if you are have you collection view setup in your storyboard.

Comment: @GerardGrundy see the update to my answer. The init method is not a safe place to reference properties on self, especially IBOutlets. I remember having a similar issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Place your code or a breakpoint in `init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)`. That should get called if you have your CollectionView added in your storyboard.

**Update**
Handle your IBOutlets as so (in your cell subclass) because in the init function they may not be valid as yet, which I assume is your case:

```
override func layoutSubviews() 
{
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    self.label.minimumScaleFactor = 0.8 //set the scale factor or minimumFontSize so that it can then start adjusting the font size.
    Self.label.numberOfLines = 1
}
```

Comment: Yes it's being called but causes an error see my EDIT to the above question.

Comment: @GerardGrundy that is typical. In the init methods your outlets may not have been initialised yet, I assume its a lazy initialisation kind of thing. Imagine initialising a view that has thousands of IBOutlets, and also subsequently initialising its subviews, and not presenting that view. That would be a waste of memory right, only until the view is presented then you want to initialise the properties on that view etc.

Comment: Ok great this is being called to set the settings but for some reason it is still displaying the text on 2 lines.  I tried : self.label.sizeToFit() but it just goes weird and the cells change size.  I'm just trying to get the text to fit the width.  Maybe I need to add a max width for the text line somewhere.

Comment: Oh right. You need to set numberOfLines on the label to 1. Try that.  'label.numberOfLines=1' from what i remember

Comment: Thats all it needed.  :-/  to set the number of lines.  Weird the label can break that in the collection view as in other circumstances you need to specify if it has multiple lines. Put that in your answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: @GerardGrundy  awesome :). Mark as correct answer here please

Comment: @GerardGrundy  yeh I agree, usually number of lines is 1 by default. Maybe you set number of lines in Storyboard. Happy you got it sorted out.

Comment: This doesn't look like a replacement for `awakeFromNib` at all - `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is/can be called several times during a view's lifetime. Better off calling `didMovetoSuperview()`