# RxSwift - Can't bind variable of custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

I have a custom `UICollectionViewCell` with a `UILabel` inside it.
Is also has the property `hour`, which is `String?` for the sake of the example.

I made a private function named `bind` to configure my bindings. Here is my class:

```
class HourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel UILabel!
    let hour Variable<String?> = Variable<String?>("")
    let disposeBag: DisposeBag = DisposeBag()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        bind()
    }

    private func bind() {
        hour.asObservable().bind(to: hourLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
        hour.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: {debugPrint("New hour: \($0 ?? "--")")}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }
}
```

Calling `bind` inside the required init might be a problem. Sometimes the `hourLabel` is still not initialized. Also, calling this function inside `init(frame: CGRect)` never gets the `bind` function to be triggered, which is awkward. I thought this function was always called.

Even though this is a simple binding, I can't achieve it correctly.

From inside my `UICollectionViewController`, I have this function which fills the `hour` property from my custom cell:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HourCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HourCollectionViewCell
        var text: String = "\(indexPath.row)"

        // This does not work because `bind` method
        // is never called.
        cell.hour.value = text

        return cell
    }
```

**UPDATE:**
I've seen that `init:coder` is called when I'm initializing the View from a Storyboard, which is the case.

A workaround that I've seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957262/custom-uicollectionviewcell-class-init-not-being-called#answers) is to call `bind` from inside `layoutSubviews`. This way everything worked. Is this the better approach?

Comment: Why no call it from `awakeFromNib`? It guarantees all @IB properties are initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Your cell is reusable, so you should clear the dispose bag.

```
class HourCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var hourLabel UILabel!
    let hour = PublishRelay<String?>()
    private(set) var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func bind() {
        hour.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: "").debug().drive( hourLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
    }

    override prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    }
}
```

I used a `PublishRelay` as `Variable` is deprecated and made it a `Driver` to make sure we're on the mainThread.
You can use `debug()` to print the events in the console.

Because on reuse we clear the disposeBag, we can call bind from within UICollectionViewController:

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HourCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HourCollectionViewCell
        var text: String = "\(indexPath.row)"

        cell.bind()
        cell.hour.accept(text)

        return cell
    }
```

I encourage you to have a look at `RxDataSources` as it's probably better for the UICollectionViewController to provide a model for each cell.

Comment: Thanks Valérian. I did this manually to enhance my knowledge about RxSwift. I have never used drivers.